# Shift and reduce sinewave

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance

I want to meausure the impedance of a sample of carbon, marked Rc in my drawing. On my FPGA I have a DAC which can provide 0-3 volts and an ADC that can read 0-3 volts. By reffering the positive input on the Op-amp(+) to the left to Vcc/2 = 1.5 V and amplifying my signal (1.5 + 1.5*sin(t))V, it looks like I get a sinewave symmetricaly around 0 with an amplitude of 15, on my oscilloscope.

I then want to measure the current through my sample with a transimpedance amplifier, while also applying a gain of 1/10 and shifting the signal to be strictly positive. Would I be able to do that with one op amp, similar to what I have drawn to the right of the Rc sample?

I am measuring a type of impedance called memristance, where the impedance depends on how much current has gone through the sample in past time. Therefore I cant have any DC voltage on top of the sinewave when I do measurements.

[image: schematic drawing]

Comment: The resistance of the carbon is a few hundred ohms. The supply voltage is +/- 15 volts. The DAC can only provide positive values, so I write a positive sinewave that oscillates around 1.5 volts and then connect the positive input to 1.5 volts, so the output will oscillate around 1.5-1.5 = 0 V. It seems to be working when I measure it, but of course I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this will likely be sufficient for your application:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7iY60.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You basically want your signal to be centered around 1.5V all the time to be able to fit into the ADC and DAC range of what I assume to be 0-3V. But there's no reason that you would need to go to ground (0V) and then back to 1.5V.

The left part is an inverting amplifier, which keeps the signal centered around 1.5V. Then you have the TIA around OA2 that will convert the current through \$R_C\$ to a voltage (\$v_{out} = -R_f\cdot i_Rc\$).

Make sure you add a low-pass filter after your TIA to avoid aliasing effects. Also, TIA's are notoriously unstable for high \$R_f\$. Add a capacitance \$C_f\$ in parallel to \$R_f\$ if you encounter stability problems, though keep in mind that you will limit the bandwidth to \$1 / (2\pi R_fC_f)\$ doing so.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer! I am measuring a type of impedance called memristance, where the impedance depends on how much current has gone through the sample in past time. Therefore I cant have any DC voltage on top of the sinewave when I do measurements. That is the reason why I shift it and then shift back again.

Comment: @Une in Sven's suggested circuit here, both ends of Rc are at the same DC potential, so there is no DC current flow through Rc.

Comment: @brhans thank you!